# Pipelining of cat and ls commands

Tags: linux, pipeline, cat, ls

I am a newbie to linux . I have been learning about cat command when i tried this .

```
harish@harish-Lenovo-G50-45:~$ cat file
Videos/Arrow/Season*
harish@harish-Lenovo-G50-45:~$ cat file | ls -l
```

The command displays the content of the current folder instead of the folder mentioned in the file .. But when i did this

```
harish@harish-Lenovo-G50-45:~$ cat file
Videos/Arrow/Season*
harish@harish-Lenovo-G50-45:~$ ls -l $(cat file)
```

The contents of the expected folder displays correctly . Why cant i not use the pipeline in this case ?

Comment: you can't "pipe" text to `ls` for use as filenames. ls doesn't accept input that way. you'd have to use xargs, e.g. `cat file|xargs ls -l`. xargs takes data from stdin and passes it to the specified command (`ls -l`) as command-line arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you are passing the output of `cat file` to the input of `ls -l`. Since `ls -l` does not take any input, it does not do anything regarding the output of `cat file`. However in the second example you are using `$(cat file)` which puts the output of `cat file` in the place of an argument passed to `ls -l`, and this time `ls -l` has the text inside `file` in the right place for doing something with it. The issue here is noticing the difference between the standard input of a program and the arguments of a program. Standard input is what you have when you call `scanf` in C, for example; and the arguments are what you get in the `argv` pointer passed as parameter to the main procedure.